# I can not understand my symptoms. Python is using pyscard

Tags: python, rfid, pyscard

I'm working on a program in Python that recognizes the Mifare Card with tkinter and writes the value to the card.

My current program is scarce but works well. However, it fails intermittently when updating the binary block on the card.
After failure, all binary blocks are changed to 0 or 255.

I can not understand the phenomenon.

The reader has failed but the card has already changed.

I want to remove the cause of the symptom and the symptom. Help.

Attach the source.

- At the time of failure

> connecting to ACS ACR122U 00 00
>
> FF CA 00 00 04 - uid get
>
> DB 96 AE 52 90 00
>
> FF 82 00 00 06 05 00 00 00 00 00 - load key
>
> [] 90 00 - success load key
>
> FF 86 00 00 05 01 00 00 60 00 - authentication
>
> [] 90 00 - success authentication
>
> FF B0 00 01 10 - number 1 binary block call
>
> 00 00 00 00 40 00 00 00 AA 55 00 00 00 40 00 00 90 00 - get number 1 binary block
>
> ------------------------ before update binary block------------------------
>
> before binary block >> [0, 0, 0, 0, 64, 0, 0, 0, 170, 85, 0, 0, 0, 64, 0, 0]
>
> before send_byte >> [0, 0, 0, 0, 64, 0, 0, 0, 170, 85, 0, 0, 0, 64, 0, 0]
>
> ---
>
> FF D6 00 01 10 00 00 00 00 40 00 00 00 AA 55 00 00 00 40 00 00 - number 1 binary block update
>
> [] 63 00 - failed
>
> ------------------------update fail binary block------------------------
>
> send byte>>[0, 0, 0, 0, 64, 0, 0, 0, 170, 85, 0, 0, 0, 64, 0, 0]
>
> ---
>
> FF 00 40 00 04 01 00 01 01 buzzer controll
>
> [] 90 00 - buzzer control success
>
> FF 00 40 00 04 01 00 01 01 buzzer controll
>
> [] 90 00 - buzzer control success
>
> FF B0 00 01 10 - number 1 binary block call
>
> [] 63 00 - failed
>
> disconnecting from ACS ACR122U 00 00

- After failure

> connecting to ACS ACR122U 00 00
>
> FF CA 00 00 04 - uid get
>
> DB 96 AE 52 90 00
>
> FF 82 00 00 06 05 00 00 00 00 00 - load key
>
> [] 90 00 - success load key
>
> FF 86 00 00 05 01 00 00 60 00 - authentication
>
> [] 90 00 - authentication success
>
> FF B0 00 01 10 - number 1 binary block call
>
> 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 90 00 - get number 1 binary block

```py
 def rf_thread(self, second=1.0):

       rf_test()
       _rf_thread = threading.Timer(second, rf_thread)
       _rf_thread.daemon = True
       _rf_thread.start()


 def rf_test():
        hresult, hcontext = SCardEstablishContext(SCARD_SCOPE_USER)
        assert hresult == SCARD_S_SUCCESS
        hresult, readers = SCardListReaders(hcontext, [])
        assert len(readers) > 0
        reader = readers[0]
        hresult, hcard, dwActiveProtocol = SCardConnect(
            hcontext,
            reader,
            SCARD_SHARE_SHARED,
            SCARD_PROTOCOL_T0 | SCARD_PROTOCOL_T1)

       # get uid
       try:
            hresult, uid = SCardTransmit(hcard, dwActiveProtocol, [0xFF, 0xCA, 0x00, 0x00, 0x04])
            key = "00000000"

            #load key  
            try:
                SELECT = [0xFF, 0x82, 0x00, 0x00, 0x06]
                DF_TELECOM = [0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00]

                hresult, response = SCardTransmit(hcard, SCARD_PCI_T1, SELECT + DF_TELECOM)

                if hresult != SCARD_S_SUCCESS:
                    print(str(SCardGetErrorMessage(hresult))
                    return []

                SELECT = [0xFF, 0x86, 0x00, 0x00, 0x05]
                DF_TELECOM = [0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x60, 0x00]


                #authentication
                try:
                    hresult, response = SCardTransmit(hcard, SCARD_PCI_T1, SELECT + DF_TELECOM)

                    if hresult != SCARD_S_SUCCESS:
                        return []

                    # Number 1 binary block get
                    req_byte = [0xFF, 0xB0, 0x00, 0x01, 0x10]
                    hresult, result_money = SCardControl(hcard, SCARD_CTL_CODE(3500), req_byte)


                    # Number 1 binary block update
                    SELECT = [0xFF, 0xD6, 0x00, 0x01, 0x10]
                    DF_TELECOM = [0, 0, 0, 0, 64, 0, 0, 0, 170, 85, 0, 0, 0, 64, 0, 0]

                    hresult, response = SCardTransmit(hcard, SCARD_PCI_T1,
SELECT + DF_TELECOM)

                    if hresult == SCARD_S_SUCCESS:
                        if response[0] == 144:
                             # some success code

                        else:
                            print("------------------------update fail binary block------------------------")
                            print("send byte>>" + str(SELECT + DF_TELECOM))
                            print("-----------------------------------------------------------")

                        try:
                            req_byte = [0xFF, 0x00, 0x40, 0x00, 0x04, 0x01, 0x00, 0x01,0x01]
                            hresult, response = SCardControl(hcard, SCARD_CTL_CODE(3500), req_byte)
                            hresult, response = SCardControl(hcard, SCARD_CTL_CODE(3500),req_byte)
                        except Exception as e:
                            print(e)

                    # Number 1 binary block get
                    res_req_byte = [0xFF, 0xB0, 0x00, 0x01, 0x10]
                    try:
                        hresult, response1 = SCardControl(hcard, SCARD_CTL_CODE(3500), res_req_byte)
                    print("after binary >>" + str(response1))

                    except Exception as e:
                        print(e)


                except Exception as e:
                    print("authentication except >>" + str(e))
            except Exception as e:
                print("load key except >> " + str(e))

       except SystemError:
            print("no card found")
       except Exception as e:
            print("uid err" + str(e))

       finally:
            hresult = SCardReleaseContext(hcontext)
            if hresult != SCARD_S_SUCCESS:
                print('Failed to release context: ' +SCardGetErrorMessage(hresult))
```

The expected result should be unchanged after the update block but intermittently changed to 0 or 255.

Comment: Is the communication with the card failing due to card tearing? I.e. is the card pulled away from the reader during the write operation?

Comment: The card is normal. This phenomenon occurs when the card moves quickly on the reader.
 It seems that Michael Roland said that when he gets out of the card and writes it out.